# How to properly create a custom field in salesforce using jsforce?

Tags: javascript, node.js, salesforce

I am trying to create a customfield in jsforce and am having a heck of a time doing it. I can create a custom object fine, but when trying to make a field so the clients users to sort their leads by it is giving me a heckof a time. This is what I did to create a object

```
var jsforce = require('jsforce');
var conn = new jsforce.Connection();
 conn.login('myemail', 'my password and token', function(err, res) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err); }
 var metadata = [{
  fullName: 'TestObject1__c',
  label: 'Test Object 1',
  pluralLabel: 'Test Object 1',
  nameField: {
    type: 'Text',
    label: 'Test Object Name'
  },
  deploymentStatus: 'Deployed',
  sharingModel: 'ReadWrite'
}];

conn.metadata.create('CustomObject', metadata, function(err, results)  {
  if (err) { console.err(err); }
  for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var result = results[i];
    console.log('success ? : ' + result.success);
    console.log('fullName : ' + result.fullName);
  }
});

  {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    console.log(res);
  }
 })
```

That works fine but it is not what I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated as the client wants this out. It is part of a larger project that we have already completed but now the fields have to be dynamically created so the end users don't have to make the fields themselves in order for us to push the data to their account. We are currently pushing stuff but its under another field whose name doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to accomplish this by making a package in the salesforce website. All my clients users have to do is to click a simple link click install and it makes a list view and creates the fields i need.